# Syntax for Azure Application Insights Failures IN filter

Tags: azure, user-interface, azure-application-insights

Azure Application Insights seems quite a cool feature.

In the Failures section, I am trying to filter failures on some ResultCode (which is actually HTTP Response Status). It seems that they have `in` and `!in` operators to filter on, but I couldn't make them work after trying 5 different syntaxes.

What I basically love to do is filter requests on `resultCode !in [400, 401, 403]`. Anyone has a clue how to use them?

[image: App Insights UI]

Comment: are you using kusto for query?

Comment: @IvanYang, I added an image to the question to bring more clarity, thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's a bug, when you use in or !in, the correct format should be: resultCode !in ("400", "401", "403"). But now it always add double quotes around (), like resultCode !in "("400", "401", "403")", which cause the error. I need to confirm, then let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently updated this control so it can be used without having to understand the intricacies of KQL syntax. You should be able to create a filter like what you're looking for by checking the boxes like this:

[image: Filter pill]

Comment: I will add that I had to remove empty spaces in the `400,401,403`

Comment: @eddyP23, we recently updated this control to make it easier to use. I'll update this answer; please let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same interface as your question, but as there's no other reactions I thought it might be better than nothing. You can find the same information if you go to `Analytics` from the overview and use a query like the following to get an overview of failed requests with your filter.

```
requests
| where timestamp >= ago(1d)
    and success  == "False" 
    and resultCode !in ("400", "401", "403")
```

Furthermore you can select `View in Analytics` when on the `Failures` blade to get the queries for the failure graphs and adjust them by adding the filter.

Comment: It's easy to get the results by using kusto. But how to do that via UI filter? I did try many times(you can see my comments above), still failed via UI.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that too, tried this sintax, doesn't work